# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (project.deps.json) was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, runtime

I am trying to run [this c# project](https://github.com/erpnet/ErpNet.FP) on a Debian virtual machine but I get the following error:

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ErpNet.FP.Server.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtimepack.Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64', version: '3.0.0'
    path: 'createdump'
```

I have installed both .NET Core 3.0 SDK and .NET Core 3.0 Runtime on the machine. I am running the ready to download and run file [Linux 64 bit, folder install](https://github.com/erpnet/ErpNet.FP#linux-64-bit-folder-install)

Answer (score 0):

Recompilling from the source (using `dotnet msbuild`) directly on the linux machine seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: Was recompiling on the linux machine the only way you got this to work?  I'm running into the same thing, but am not able to compile source on the target machine. I'm trying to publish self-contained for a linux target, from a Windows host. I was trying to avoid even having to install the runtime on the target machine and rely on the self-contained publish.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only way I got it to work.

Comment: In my case it ended up being my own problem.  I was getting this exact same error - missing "createdump".  I was publishing locally, zipping up the published files, and copying them to the destination server.  It turned out that my zip command wasn't including files without an extension; "createdump" was correctly being generated in the build but wasn't in the archive.  Fixing that and it all worked as expected!

Comment: @PeterTirrell thank you so much. The error message is terrible. Very hard to deduct that 'createdump' is the file actually missing, it suggests that the runtime package is missing.